# What XPath I should use to extract contents of a <div> preceded by another <div> with specific label?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, extract

I need to extract car specs and features of all cars from carpages.co.uk, example page http://www.carpages.co.uk/guide/bmw/bmw-3-series-318i-se.asp and each feature have an image with ALT tags: standard / optional / not applicable

```
//div/following::div[contains(.,"Power Steering")]//img/@alt
```

I tried the above XPath but it get every row of features instead of getting only ALT tag of the the row I labelled it, in this example Power Steering. Removing a slash from //img made it to not extract anything.

I also need to extract other specifications such as Power, Torque, etc.

Can someone help me with a working XPath?

Comment: this captures (nearly?) all the info: `//div[@id='guide-body']/div[@class='lcol' or @class='rcol' or @class='rcolr' or @class='price-tag']`

Comment: I think that you don't understand how a car database should be made to be usable, each row should be one car and each column should be one feature, so I need to XPath individually each feature based on the label of preceding <div>.

There was one more person before you who posted a similar XPath that get all features instead of one by one, and he deleted comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
//div[contains(., "Power Steering")]/following::div[1]/img/@alt
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this format of XPath works for every field EXCEPT these 2 fields:

//div[contains(., "CO2 Emissions")]/following::div[1] and //div[contains(., "Car Insurance Group")]/following::div[1]

Can you tell me also how to extract these 2 things?